# How to download Json data on Amazon S3 Server

Tags: java, rest, amazon-s3

I have a https://link, which returns me a json object with 50gb of data. I want to download this json using a java code directly to S3. Or any other tool which can download this data directly to s3.

I really tried few ways from a java code I can download about 200Mb of data but when size increases its fail.

I need a help here.

Comment: *"its fail"* ... okay, in what way does it fail?  What's the error?  In any event, it shouldn't fail, and **any** common tool should be able to handle this, such as `curl` or `wget`, for example.  S3 supports objects up to 5TB, and there's no fundamental reason why any standard HTTP client wouldn't be able to download an object of any size from S3.

Comment: Question is not clear if you are uploading to S3 or downloading from S3. If uploading then the maximum you can PUT in a single request is 5Gb. At a minimum you will need to use a multipart upload.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, there is data limit at network level (routers etc...)

You have two options : 1. write a paginated write api and an file merge API (download in pieces and merge) 2. Increase the limits everywhere (switches, routers E3)

The easier and better IMO approach is 1st one where you can write few services to download verify and proceed and finally merge.

Answer (score 0):

```
wget -O file "https://link"
```

If the https://link can be downloaded via web browser, then the above command will write the output to 'file'.